# Solenoid Valve blowing power LED - how can i protect the LED?

Tags: protection, 12v, solenoid-valve

I have this simple circuit setup and working well to turn a solenoid valve on (close it) and off (open it again) for a watering system I use.

missing is an on/off switch before the VCC.  However, I have an LED connected to indicate when I have my switch on (system ready/on).  If I leave the relay in the "ON" position (so the solenoid is powered), switch the system off, then back on again (powering the solenoid on, because the relay is latching and left in the on position), sometimes the LED blows (i.e. stops working and i have to replace it).

I want the feature of leaving the relay in the on position (why I chose a latching version), but how can I protect the LED from whatever is happening (I assume a negative over voltage is being created by the solenoid??).

[image: circuit example]

Comment: LEDs will take a brief over-current quite well, but can be quite vulnerable to reverse voltage. Try a signal diode (1N4148 etc) backwards across the LED.

Answer (score 4):

Connect a reverse biased diode in parallel to the solenoid, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f44GjQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That will prevent the solenoid from generating voltage spikes when turning off.

Comment: thanks... what rating should I look for? I assume anything above 12v, and what 3.5A (the amperage rating of the operation solenoid?).

Comment: @warath-coder, yes. Preferably, the diode should be fast, so that the voltage does not rise too much.

Comment: so I want voltage rating close to 12v... but what about amperage rating? 200mA seems to be a very common rating. Also, the 1N4148 seems to start at 75v :(

Comment: The reverse voltage rating  of the diode has to be higher than your power supply rating. You can use any diode with voltage rating > 12V and peak forward current rating >4A. 1N400x series could work (continuous rating 1A, but peak rating 30A).

Comment: Thank you! I have a 1N4007 1000V/1A, and will try that...